# Ajax keeps refreshing entire page with a tag

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax

I'm implementing a like/unlike button with PHP, SQL and Ajax. The buttons work and a user can like for a maximum number of 1 time.

Posts are being pulled from the SQL database with a foreach loop, where every item is represented by a bootstrap card. Now, every time someone presses the like/unlike button the entire page refreshes, leaving the user lost in his tracks. I'd like to update the card which like/unlike button was pressed only.

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // when user likes
                $('.like').click(function(){
                    var postid = $(this).attr('id');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'like.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        async: false,
                        data: {
                            'liked': 1,
                            'postid': postid
                        },
                        success:function(){

                        }
                    })
                });

                //when user unlikes
                $('.unlike').click(function(){
                    var postid = $(this).attr('id');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'like.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        async: false,
                        data: {
                            'unliked': 1,
                            'postid': postid
                        },
                        success:function(){

                        }
                    })
                });
            })
        </script>
```

With the following PHP/HTML code for obtaining every card from the database:

```
<div class="card bg-white mb-2">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- add title for question/tip -->
                <?php
                if($item['type'] == 'tip') {
                ?>
                <div class="col-8"><h5 class="card-title text-left"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o text-color-policeblue"></i>
                        <?php
                        }
                        elseif ($item['type'] == 'vraag') {
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-8"><h5 class="card-title text-left"><i class="fa fa-comments text-color-policeblue"></i>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                                &nbsp;
                                <?php
                                echo $item['title'];
                                ?>

                            </h5></div>
                        <div class="col-4 text-right">
                            <?php
                            if ($item['tipRedactie'] == 1) {
                                ?>
                                <i class="fa fa-check text-color-policeblue"></i>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                            <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-bookmarks" fill="#004687" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v11.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.777.416L7 13.101l-4.223 2.815A.5.5 0 0 1 2 15.5V4zm2-1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v10.566l3.723-2.482a.5.5 0 0 1 .554 0L11 14.566V4a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H4z"/>
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.268 1H12a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v11.768l.223.148A.5.5 0 0 0 14 13.5V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H6a2 2 0 0 0-1.732 1z"/>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <!-- add name and date -->
                <p class="small font-italic text-left mt-n2">
                    <?php
                    if ($item['anonymous'] == '1') {
                        echo 'Anoniem';
                    }
                    else {
                        $userName = getUser($item['userId']);
                        if ($userName['username'] != '') {
                            echo($userName['username']);
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    ·
                    <?php
                    echo date('d/m/Y', $item['timestamp']);
                    ?>
                </p>
                <p class="card-text text-left">
                    <?php
                    echo $item['itemText'];
                    ?>
                </p>
                <p class="small font-italic text-left mt-n2">
                    <?php
                    $domains = returnItemDomains($item['id']);
                    foreach($domains as $domain) {
                        echo '#'.$domain. ' ';
                    }
                    ?>
                </p>
                <div class="row text-left">
                    <div class="col">
                        <!-- Message icon -->
                        <a href="reactions.php?id=<?php echo $item['id']; ?>">
                            <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-chat-right-fill" fill="#004687" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14 0a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12.793a.5.5 0 0 1-.854.353l-2.853-2.853a1 1 0 0 0-.707-.293H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12z"/>
                            </svg>
                            <!-- add number of reactions -->
                            <?php
                            $countReactions = count(returnItemReaction($item['id']));
                            echo $countReactions;
                            if ($countReactions == 1) {
                                echo ' reactie';
                            }
                            else {
                                echo ' reacties';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </a>
                        <!-- Upvote icon -->
                        <svg width="1.5em" height="1.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-caret-up-fill" fill="#004687" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M7.247 4.86l-4.796 5.481c-.566.647-.106 1.659.753 1.659h9.592a1 1 0 0 0 .753-1.659l-4.796-5.48a1 1 0 0 0-1.506 0z"/>
                        </svg>
                        <!-- add number of upvotes -->
                        <?php
                        $countLikes = returnItemLikes($item['id']);
                        echo $countLikes;

                        $userLikes = getLikeUser($userId, $item['id']);
                        ?>
                        <a href="" class="like" id="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>">
                        <?php
                        if($userLikes == 0) {
                            if ($countLikes == 1) {
                                echo ' upvote';
                            } else {
                                echo ' upvotes';
                            }
                        ?>
                                </a>
                        <?php
                        }
                        else {
                        ?>
                        <a href="" class="unlike" id="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>">
                         <?php
                            echo ' upvotes downvote';
                        }
                        ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The like.php page for handling the like/unlike queries is as follow:

```
<?php
    $userId = getUserIdBySessionId($_COOKIE['SESSIONID']);
    if (isset($_POST['liked'])) {
        $postid = $_POST['postid'];
        insertLikeItem($userId, $postid);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['unliked'])) {
        $postid = $_POST['postid'];
        deleteLikeItem($userId, $postid);
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `preventDefault()` method when user clicks like or unlike so that browser won't try change url or refresh the page.

```
$('.like').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //your remaining code here
}
```

Same with unlike...

```
$('.unlike').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //your remaining code here
}
```